# Launching camera camera from app does not have pro camera mode

Tags: java, android, mobile-application, samsung-galaxy-camera

On the Samsung Galaxy S6, when taking a picture there is an option to use Pro Camera mode which gives access to various extra settings when taking a picture.

In my application when I launch the camera activity

```
Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);
```

I don't have the Pro camera mode available. Is there a way to have the pro mode in my app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to android as well, but in your case, I think that the "Pro Camera Mode" is part of the Camera App. 
In that case, I don't think you could accomplish what you are asking.
My solution would be, if you know what functions you want to use in the Pro Camera Mode, you could instead program those individual functions into your app.